# Why does my apt-platform filter not filter as expected?

Tags: api-platform.com

I have this filter on this entity:

```
@ApiFilter(SearchFilter::class, properties={"shortName":"exact"})
```

When I test with this url in Postman:

```
{{path}}/levels?shortName=TOTO
```

I get some lines with other values than the wished filter. What is wrong with my filter?

```
{
"@context": "/evaluation/api/contexts/Level",
"@id": "/evaluation/api/v1/levels",
"@type": "hydra:Collection",
"hydra:member": [
    {
        "@id": "/evaluation/api/v1/levels/524701de-448b-4380-875c-ff6debfafc8c",
        "@type": "Level",
        "id": "524701de-448b-4380-875c-ff6debfafc8c",
        "shortName": "IN_ACQUISITION",
        "position": 20,
        "priority": 20,
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the filter like `{{path}}/levels?shortName[]=TOTO` (note the square brackets) as [described in the documentation](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/filters/#search-filter). Otherwise it will get ignored and you get the results returned as if the query component of your URL was non-existent.

Comment: Hi Simon. thanks for your reply. I re tried this morning + clear the cache. And it works fine. My code was ok .... Sorry for this question. Merci